# Как обновить файлы на клиенте, если на сервере он изменился?

Tags: javascript, html, кэширование

Когда кидаю файлы на сервер и захожу на сайт, сайт(html, css, js и медиафайлы) обновляется только после рефреша.
Пробовал добавить кнопку "Проверка обновлений", которая просто обновляет страницу, но это очень не удобно. Других идей нет.

Comment: Во-первых, если вы не запретили клиенту использовать кэш, то клиент пойдёт за данными в кэш и не будет скачивать обновления с сервера. Во-вторых, даже если запретили, обновить страницу тем или иным образом всё равно придётся

Comment: websocket может помочь.

Comment: @AlexSazonov , HTTP2  вроде тоже  должно работать